# how to extract and pass the value in Json extractor in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

can Anyone tell how to extract x value using token extractor

```
{ "access" :[     
    {"x":"1234566","c":"qwer"}, 
    {"y":"12344532566","b":"asdf"}, 
    {"z":"12358b2","a":"zxcv"} ] }
```

i tried this `$.access[1].x` but when i log it prints the value for me as null

as i want to pick and pass this value of x in new request parameter.

[image]

when i pass `name of create variable`  `modi` in request parameter instead of passing value of x it does pass modi only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set Match Nr to -1 it extracts all matches  which are named:

- modi_1
- modi_2
  ...
- modi_x

and indeed variable modi is null

So just replace -1 by 1 to get first match or by 0 to get a random match

Regarding the json path, it looks ok to me. you can check it using View Result Tree And renderer Json Path tester

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `$.access[1]` [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression returns `{"y":"12344532566","b":"asdf"}`, there is no `x` attribute there because in [JSON Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) entries indices are [zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) to you need to amend your JSONPath query to look like `$.access[0].x` or use [deep scan operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) to be just `$..x`
2. Remove this `-1` from "Match Nr" as you're extracting only a single value

   [image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)